# Ожидание выполнения скрипта

Tags: php, javascript

Есть скрипт на php, при его выполнении происходит стоп и затем старт сервера Apache. Причем апач рестартуется на этом же сервере, на котором работает скрипт. скрипт фактически запускает командный файл, который стоп-старт делает апач. С помошью чего можно сделать так, чтобы при выполнении данного скрипта происходило ожидание и потом возврат к этой же странице. Фактически так примерно сделано на домашних роутерах, когда жмешь кнопку рестарта и появляется ползунок ожидания и потом возврат уже к этой же странице после рестарта роутера.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript должен периодически посылать аякс-запросы. Как только запрос выполнился без ошибок - сервер запустился